# how i can get value from column id to another page using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, web

```
 $("#table1").append(
    "<tr><td id='keyId'>" +
      key +
      "</td><td>" +
      name +
      "</td><td>" +
      address +
      "</td><td><ul><li>" +
      foodName +
      "</li></ul></td><td>" +
      phone +
      "</td><td>" +
      total +
      "</td></tr>"
  );
```

This is the code of my index.js I want the value of key row when the button was clicked, that value will be used to give the details. I want to use that value in other javascript file or html file.

Comment: look into localstorage

Comment: could you share more information? Such as the structure of your project and usage of the value

Comment: Are you mean info from another row in table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Window localStorage properties allow to save key/value pairs in a web browser.

Syntax in your first page for SAVING data to localStorage:

```
localStorage.setItem("key", "value");
```

Syntax in your second page for READING data from localStorage:

```
var lastname = localStorage.getItem("key");
```

Syntax for REMOVING data from localStorage:

```
localStorage.removeItem("key");
```

Comment: Thanks for solution. I am fetching data from table but when i click on button only first value get fetched.

Comment: You may need `var colel= $('#col-id').closest('tr')` to get row element. Then for each col you can do `var secondcolval = colel.find('td').eq(1)`. You better put class in every col tag, then you can use col name instead of index: `var secondcolval = colel.find('.secondcol').text()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use SessionStorage or LocalStorage.

> The sessionStorage object stores data for only one session
> (the data is deleted when the browser tab is closed).
>
> The localStorage object stores data with no expiration date. The data
> will not be deleted when the browser is closed, and will be available
> the next day, week, or year.

The examples below are for LocalStorage but  you can use it with SessionStorage as well, depending on your needs, their syntax to set/get/remove items is the same.

You don't necessarily have to remove items from SessionStorage since it will be cleared automatically when you close the tab. For LocalStorage, it's a good practice to remove the item if you don't need it anymore.

1st page:

```
$("#table1").append(
  "<tr><td id='keyId'>" +
    key +
    "</td><td>" +
    name +
    "</td><td>" +
    address +
    "</td><td><ul><li>" +
    foodName +
    "</li></ul></td><td>" +
    phone +
    "</td><td>" +
    total +
    "</td></tr>"
);

<script>
  var button = document.getElementById(keyId);
  button.onclick = function(){
    // Add item to localStorage
    localStorage.setItem("keyId", this.innerText);
  };
</script>
```

2nd page:

```
<script>
// Retrieve
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("keyId");
// Remove if not needed
localStorage.removeItem("keyId");
</script>
```

[sessionStorage on w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_sessionstorage.asp)
[localStorage on w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp)